# How to make one tag become an attribute of another nested tag

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to create an xsl file that transforms an existing xml file into another format. While I have am able to convert most of the file, the problem I am having is with processing the first half of the file. The xml file I am working on is represented by this simple example:

```
<generic_etd>
   <associated_tags>
      <master>
         <dc.contributor>contributor</dc.contributor>
      </master>
      <related>
         <dc.contributor.role>contributor role</dc.contributor.role>
      </related> 
   </associated_tags>
   <associated_tags>
      <master>
         <dc.contributor>sponsor</dc.contributor>
      </master>
      <related>
         <dc.contributor.role>sponsor role</dc.contributor.role>
      </related>
   </associated_tags>
   <dc.creator>gradstudent2</dc.creator>
   <dc.date>2014-02-11</dc.date>
   <dc.description>description</dc.description>
   <thesis.degree.discipline>Business Administration</thesis.degree.discipline>
</generic_etd>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to take the information in each associated_tag to produce the following:

```
<etd_ms:contributor role="contributor role">contributor</etd_ms:contributor_role>
<etd_ms:contributor role="sponsor role">sponsor</etd_ms:contributor_role>
```

So the goal here is to make what is in the related tag an attribute of what is in the master tag. Since I am new at xsl, I am not even sure how to start to tackle this. Is this even possible?

**EDIT:** I should also point out that the tags within the master and related tags can be different. In this particular example they are the same but that isn't necessarily always going to be the case.

Thanks.

Comment: how you're able to convert most of the file but not able to convert left section? what's the problem?

Comment: Will there always be exactly these two associated tags (master and related) within the `<associated tags>` parent?

Comment: My problem is that I am used to processing files one line at at time, and not having to down one tree to get information, then down another tree to the other information that I need. Like I said I am new at xsl processing so I am just unsure how to proceed.

Comment: @michael.hor257k yes there will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well then this should be quite simple, except one or two things:

1. First, your example output lacks a root element.
2. Secondly, you show a `etd_ms:` namespace prefix on the output
   elements; this prefix  must be declared and bound to a namespace somewhere in the stylesheet.
3. Lastly, your output elements have mismatched opening and closing tags: `<etd_ms:contributor` vs.`</etd_ms:contributor_role>`

Other than that, try the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:etd_ms="http://www.yournamespacehere.com">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<output>
    <xsl:for-each select="generic_etd/associated_tags">
        <etd_ms:contributor>
            <xsl:attribute name="role"><xsl:value-of select="related/dc.contributor.role"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="master/dc.contributor"/>
        </etd_ms:contributor>       
    </xsl:for-each>
</output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input (corrected to fix the closing element), this produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<output xmlns:etd_ms="http://www.yournamespacehere.com">
   <etd_ms:contributor role="contributor role">contributor</etd_ms:contributor>
   <etd_ms:contributor role="sponsor role">sponsor</etd_ms:contributor>
</output>
```

Comment: That is a very elequent solution, but what if the tags between the master and related tags can be any tag/value?

Comment: Then change the explicit reference to them by name to `*`.